# Can't start new activity from Asynchronous Method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Trying to start a new activity from an asynchronous method but for some reason the activity won't start

```
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        try {
            if (qResult.equals(userinfo[1])) {
                File file = new File("info");
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                fw.write(userinfo[0] + "\n" + userinfo[1]);
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context,OtherActivity.class));
```

I passed the context of the current activity in by adding it as one of the parameters in the constructor as such:

```
class CreateFileConnectToDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    Activity activity;
    Context context;    //ELIMINA COGLIONE
    String qResult = "";

    public CreateFileConnectToDatabase(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    }
```

however it won't start the new activity despite reaching the onPostExecute method. Am I unable to call a new activity to start from a nested asynchronous class?

Comment: Please post more code how you call Async Class execute method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the context in your AsyncTask constructor to get the right activity context so:

```
public CreateFileConnectToDatabase(Context context){
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

and call it passing your activity or fragment context:

```
new CreateFileConnectToDatabase(yourcontext).execute();
```

O.T. the comment `//ELIMINA COGLIONE` took me off the chair.

Comment: His problem is that he is starting the activity using a Context that is not an activity context, therefore he needs to add the flag to start the new activity to that intent (or he could just use the activity...)